# Context scope anomaly

Tags: c#, scope

I'm programming in C#, and I'm running into a very strange error while working with xaml.cs code-behind.  I've found a workaround, but it's a huge hack:

This does not work - fails silently.  When I put a breakpoint in, I get this error when I try to watch fileList:

"fileList does not exist within the current context."

```
void item_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    // Does not work even if on two separate lines.

    IList<string> fileList = new List<string>(); 

    TreeViewItem _item = (TreeViewItem)sender;
    FileName = _item.Tag as string;

    fileList = Directory.GetFiles(FileName, "*.extension").ToList();

    // Other stuff to be done with fileList here, which has not been coded yet.

    OnDirectoryChanged(FileName, EventArgs.Empty);  // Breakpoint here
}
```

This is the hack that works:

```
IList<string> fileList;

void item_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    fileList = new List<string>();
    TreeViewItem _item = (TreeViewItem)sender;
    FileName = _item.Tag as string;
    fileList = Directory.GetFiles(FileName, "*.xls?").ToList();

    // Other stuff to be done with fileList here, which has not been coded yet.

    OnDirectoryChanged(FileName, EventArgs.Empty);  // Breakpoint here
}
```

What I want to know is this: WHY?

Comment: On which line do you put the breakpoint?

Comment: Are you building with compiler optimizations enabled?

Comment: Preston:  As far as I know, no.  I haven't changed the compiler settings at all.

AlexD:  Look for the "// Breakpoint here" in the posted code.

Comment: Is it Debug or Release?

Comment: AlexD - I'm debugging in "release" mode.  I didn't actually intend to be, and both are configured the same way, however that's a good catch.  

... interestingly, the problem goes away in debug mode.  Good catch!

(Now, for a second upvote, can you explain what the difference between ddebug and release mode is in this case?)

Comment: ... and now it's working in release mode as well.  Voodoo!

Comment: @StevenC.Britton The difference (well, one of) is that by default "Optimize code" is OFF in Debug and ON if Release. See Project properties -> Build. (BTW, if you add `@` in front of AlexD, I'll be notified automatically about the reply :) )

Comment: @AlexD Excellent.  Wasn't sure if this used the twitter-style approach.  Anyway, that makes sense; I just ran into it again.  The strange thing is I ran it in release mode after posting my last message and it worked.  Then I wrote more code, forgot to change it to debug mode, and it didn't again.  Oh well... there we go.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot, Steven: I would suggest inviting Preston, who mentioned compiler optimization first, to make a formal answer :). Good to know that the issue was clarified and good luck!

Comment: @PrestonGuillot - I would be very much obliged if you'd write up a formal answer to this question so I can mark it as answered - you'll get some rep points, and we'll get the question off the "unanswered" list. :)